# Need help understanding speedup in parallel computing

Tags: parallel, computer-architecture

I am currently studying computer architecture and I am having some trouble understanding the concept of speedup in parallel computing. I came across the following statement: "Before the multicore era, speedup by executing programs in parallel was basically not possible." However, I am not quite sure what this means or how it relates to the concept of parallel computing.

As far as my understanding goes, parallel computing refers to the use of multiple processors or cores to execute a program or set of instructions simultaneously, which can potentially lead to a faster execution time. However, I am not clear on how this relates to the statement that speedup was not possible before the multicore era.

I would appreciate any help or clarification on this topic. If anyone could explain the concept of speedup in parallel computing in simpler terms or provide me with any references or resources to better comprehend this topic, I would be grateful.

Comment: The statement is wrong.  Also, you're bittscoterie right?  Maybe just use one username at a time since all of your questions are related.

Comment: Useful search term from that era : Amdahl's Law

Comment: How are you going to sync up two discrete processors so the pass data efficiently and speed up everything rather than bog down with overhead?

Comment: @DKNguyen: Multi-master buses have been around since the early days of computing. They are quite capable of supporting multiple CPUs in a shared-memory architecture. Think "coarse-grained parallelism" -- i.e., multiple threads -- rather than "fine-grained parallelism" such as vectorizing math operations.

Comment: Thread-level parallelism using [transputer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transputer) networks and other forms of multiprocessing were around well before multi-core processors became mainstream.

Answer (score 2):

> parallel computing refers to the use of multiple processors or cores to execute a program or set of instructions simultaneously

Yes. The processors can be cores inside the same packages, or several processors inside the same box, or in different boxes, or in different computers, in different buildings, or even halfway across the world. If a problem is chopped into slices that are executed in parallel on several processors, it's parallel computing no matter where the processors are.

> I am not clear on how this relates to the statement that speedup was not possible before the multicore era.

The statement is wrong: parallel computing existed long before multicore CPUs. But there's a grain of truth in it, or rather two grains of truth.

First, before everyone had a multicore CPU in their computer, few people had access to machines capable of parallelism. Thus there was no point for programmers of general purpose CPU-bound applications to implement it, as the extra effort would not result in more software sales. Multi-CPU computers were either big servers or supercomputers, so the only applications developed to take advantage of multiple CPUs were either server apps (webserver, database, etc) or special-purpose supercomputing applications. Now that everyone has multi-core CPU, implementing parallel processing will result in large performance gains so developers have a huge incentive to actually do it. Thus a lot more applications use parallel processing.

Note I'm not talking about multithreading to do something useful while waiting for IO, which is another question entirely.

Second, performance of parallel computing is limited by things like data sharing, coordination, parts of the problem that can't be parallelized, etc. To summarize, if you cut your problem in slices but the slices aren't independent and need results from other slices in order to proceed, then your processors won't be able to work on their slice independent from the others. They will have to talk to each other, exchange data, acquire locks, etc. The more time is spent doing this, the less time is available for actual computation. Since communication overhead tends to grow with the number of cores that have to communicate, often the small bit of code that can't be parallelized sets an upper limit on total performance no matter how many cores you throw at it, then if you throw even more cores at it, it gets slower.

The speed of light sets an upper bound for the speed at which information can travel. Cores that are closer will have less communication latency, and cores that are on the same chip can share cache efficiently and communicate even faster. This means a multicore chip has a huge advantage compared to a multi-CPU computer, or a multi-box computer, or multiple computers. Its cores communicate with lower latency, and memory is shared between cores. So if a problem requires lots of shared data or lots of communications between parallel processes, but not that much actual processing time, a multicore chip can be faster than other hardware with more processors, which imply a larger size, higher latency and lower data throughput between processes.

This means multicore is pretty versatile and pretty good at many everyday problems, and it's cheap. Unlike a supercomputer or a multi-CPU box, it doesn't require fancy hardware or motherboards with high speed interconnects between CPUs, all the parallel complexity is hidden in the CPU. So while parallel processing was certainly possible before, multicore makes it a hell of a lot cheaper and available.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems self-explanatory. If one factory worker can produce a pound of nails a day, how many pounds of nails can 10 workers produce a day? 10, right? Now just replace factory worker with cores and to the most basic measure your question is answered. How can one factory worker parallelize his work without other workers? Ignore technology in my analogy.

Let's say a customer only needs 1 pound of nails, but wants it fast. As long as the workers each have their own equipment, 10 workers could give the customer the 1 lb of nails in 1/10th of a day since each can produce 1/10th of a lb in 1/10th of a day. Same thing in computing. Before multicores, you just had one processor that could work on things.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer only has one core, it cannot process things in parallel. Therefore if you only have a computer with one core, you can't speed things up by doing parallel processing.

If you have two computers with one core each, you can sometimes speed things up by processing half of the work on computer A, and half of the work on computer B, in parallel. But who has two computers? Most people don't - especially decades ago when they were a lot more expensive. If you make a video game, for example, the people who want to play the game don't have two computers, so you can't use this idea to get parallel processing, either.

Comment: You are missing the concept and history of multiprocessor  computers.  In the late 1990’s and early 2000’s  computers with up to 8 tightly coupled Intel CPUs were offered by Compaq, Dell, Hitachi, IBM and many others.